# How to set auto layout for custom view cell in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I am working with custom table view cell and stuck in auto layout provided by ios 8, I have a requirement to have a green color view at the starting as well as at the ending. I do it but while running it in iphone 6 i get the view as below

Is there any way to set constraint on custom tableviewcell

[image: Iphone 6 view] [image]

Comment: check the following article http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: I already read your suggested link, It means we need to write codes to do so.  and line - "Add a new class to the DeviantArtBrowser project and name it RWBasicCell. Make it a subclass of UITableViewCell; make sure Also create xib file is not checked; and make sure that the language is set as Objective-C." says not to have a xib while i need to have it.

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        checkNumberOfCell = checkNumberOfCell + 1;
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithCell];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [gridDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}`

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote while they have no idea about the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use autolayout in a xib file just as you use it in any storyboard

This is what you have
[image: This is what you have]

You must select each of the two views and do the following: Add constraints for top, bottom and left or right, Also you must set the width of the element, in my case I set it as 20.

[image: add constraints]

Update the frame to fix visual issues

[image]

Now it should work on any devices

[image]

You now need to do the same for the left view and you are done

If you are working for iOS8  I would suggest reading this adaptive layout [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Comment: see the comment below your question

Comment: I found that my table view size is according to the device but the actual problem arise with the right side view i need to set a constraint on it to have a right side area.